# Django How to add a default Variation when creating a new Item

Tags: python, django

I have created a an item model with variation and variation Manager model.

I want to add a default variation function so that when I create a new item a default of size variations is created small medium and large.

I edited the question by adding a Signal but getting an error so I trying to reach somewhere now I'm getting `name 'created' is not defined`

Here is the model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')


VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size', 'size',),
    ('color', 'color',),
    ('package', 'package'),
)


class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = VariationManager()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def add_default_Variant(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    small_size, size = Variation.objects.get_or_create(
        title='Small', item=instance)
    medium_size, size = Variation.objects.get_or_create(
        title='Medium', item=instance)
    large_size, size = Variation.objects.get_or_create(
        title='Large', item=instance)

    if created:
        instance.save()
        print(f"default variant created : {variant}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use signals to add what you want [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

> this signal will create a new variant each time you save a new item
>   you can put in **models.py** or follow the docs to set it in a separated .py file

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def add_default_Variant(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    variant= Variation.objects.create(title="default variant title",item=instance)
```

> Adding your variants

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def add_default_Variant(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    small_size = Variation.objects.create(product=instance, category='size', title='Small')
    medium_size = Variation.objects.create(product=instance, category='size', title='Medium')
    large_size = Variation.objects.create(product=instance, category='size', title='Large')
```

Comment: I am finding difficulty writing the code could you help?

Comment: I added a code as you indicated but I am getting another error

Comment: type object 'Variation' has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Variation.objects not object

Comment: just copy the line 
variant, created = Variation.objects.get_or_create(title="default variant title",item=instance) 
as I wrote it

Comment: I've amended it but it is showing `name 'created' is not defined`, sorry but I new to Django. New Code made is in the question